# how to generate a pojo for a xsd schema over http using xjc

Tags: java, xsd, pojo, xjc

I am executing the following command-

xjc  -nv link1 link2 etc .

and i am getting the following errors-

parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Ref" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
  line 554 of http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to generate a pojo for the entire Spring Beans XSD? That makes no sense.

Comment: I want to understand if we can generate POJO's from any such XSD?

Comment: Also, at run time i want to change the JNDI databases. So, I checked the xML file which has this configuration. It was referring these XSDs. So I figured, if i can have the appropriate XSD's may be i can generate a POJO and at run time populate these values and marshall it into the xml file?